# Scripts in rc.local (start at boot), doesnot start

Tags: shell, debian, shell-script, boot

In my Debian `/etc/rc.local`, I've put 2 scripts (one for Wifi AP, the other for VPN client-connection):

```
sh /bootscripts/vpn.sh &
sh /bootscripts/wifiap.sh &

#test:
date >> /home/user24/Desktop/logdate

exit 0
```

Both scripts are executable (`rwxr-xr-x`), and their shebang line is `#!bin/bash`.

**But they don't run. Where am I wrong?**

Comment: Why do you source the scripts in the background that is counter-intuitive to me? Have you tried just running them in the background without using `source`?

Comment: I m doing it now. I thought `source` is needed cause I call a script in another script.

Comment: @all FYI: When you call 'source' (or its alias '.'), you insert the script in the current bash process. So you could read variables set by the script.

When you call 'sh', you initiate a fork (sub-process) that runs a new session of /bin/sh, which is usually a symbolic link to bash. In this case, environment variables set by the sub-script would be dropped when the sub-script finishes.

Comment: No `source` is only necessary if you want to have the statements in the script to have effect in rc.local itself (ie. set variables, etc.).

Comment: @Anthon Thanks. Allright, I have editted my post with  a date test. Date works. But Vpn doesnt, nor wifiAP **even with 'sh'**.

Comment: I digged it... my wifi.sh works alone, but is I *sh /etc/rc.local*, I see the echos but in the end it doenswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `/etc/rc.local` is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel, it's not the correct place to add start scripts. **I recommend to not use `/etc/rc.local` in any way.** It's a reclit for early *nix times. Instead of that, create a startup script in `/etc/init.d/name` which accepts `start` and `stop` arguments to start or stop the deamon, process or the job:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/name
#

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting name"
    your_service --with --parameters
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping name"
    kill your_service
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/name {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Also there is a skeleton script in `/etc/init.d/skeleton` for this.

After you created that scripts, set the permissons:

```
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/name
```

Now, add them to the boot seqence:

```
update-rc.d name defaults
```

This will create the necessary links in the `/etc/rc*.d/` directories.

Comment: Great, but my service are 2 loooon scripts, how do I manage this fact that way ?

Comment: @Strukt what are loooon scripts?

Comment: I mean I must call .sh ... well, I need to make 2 services, and call start/stop in my primary service intented for boot. Thank you, you lighted it all!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480897/5132 `/etc/init.d/skeleton` is no more, and that has not been the template style since 2014.